# <3>WSL (12) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:570: execvpe /usr/bin/zsh

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

This type of error appeared more and more often until it ate WSL (or I forgot how to work around it).

Started about the time I upgraded to WSL2 and installed Docker Desktop.

As far as customizations: I did instally zsh, and I hated it so I removed it; I've added a bashrc file and listed bin/zsh, but it removed itself every time I started wsl (I will probably link that thread later); **I also installed python3, and that was a complex process that could have broken things**; I did an update and upgrade on first run.

Yes, I did reinstall Debian--this did not resolve the errors.

```
> debian
<3>WSL (10) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:570: execvpe /usr/bin/zsh failed 2
<3>WSL (10) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:579: Create process not expected to return
> wsl
<3>WSL (12) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:570: execvpe /usr/bin/zsh
<3>WSL (13) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:579: Create process not expected to return
> wsl --setdefault Debian
> wsl.exe --user root
<3>WSL (12) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:570: execvpe /usr/bin/zsh
<3>WSL (13) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:579: Create process not expected to return
> wsl --set-default-version 1
> wsl --set-default-version 2
> mkdir /usr/bin/zsh
> wsl
<3>WSL (12) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:570: execvpe /usr/bin/zsh
<3>WSL (13) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:579: Create process not expected to return
```

At a loss for what else to try, here.  Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I did install zsh, and I hated it so I removed it

It looks like you may have forgotten to reset your shell to Bash, though.  So after uninstalling Zsh, WSL is still attempting to start it but failing to find it.  This would be the same with "normal" Debian as well, but with a slightly different message.  WSL makes it a bit easier to recover, though.

Try:

```
wsl ~ -e chsh
```

Set it to `/usr/bin/bash` and then try starting again.

The `-e` is the application that you want WSL to run initially as the "shell".  You could also start with:

```
wsl ~ -e bash
```

And then run the `chsh`.

Or, if you've forgotten your password (from the comments):

```
wsl ~ -u root -e chsh Wolfpack08
```

This will run as root (no password required) and reset the shell for the `Wolfpack08` user.  For good measure:

```
wsl ~ -u root -e passwd Wolfpack08
```

... to reset your user's password as well.

Comment: `You may not change the shell for 'Wolfpack08'.`  Respones to first command.  Second did get me into bash.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 No worries - See edit ;-)

Comment: Gladly, this got me back into wsl, but since I haven't used it for so long, I don't remember my root password either.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your distro is set as default. I had some issues where my default distro was assigned to my docker desktop.
open your terminal and type `wsl -l -v` to list your distros then something like this:

```
wsl --setdefault DISTRO-NAME
```

Not sure if this will fix your problem but it is worth a try, it fixed mine though.

Answer (score 0):

for those who have this problem and also encounter `You may not change the shell for <username>`,

first restart wsl once (not necessary I guess. but anyway):

```
wsl --shutdown
```

then go to wsl again with this command:

```
wsl ~ -e bash
```

then install zsh again.

```
sudo apt install zsh
```

then go out of wsl and in again (it will open with zsh):

```
exit
wsl
```

then run following command and in prompt just type `/bin/bash`

```
chsh
# when prompted, type /bin/bash
```

go out and in one more time. then if you like, you can uninstall zsh

```
sudo apt --purge remove zsh
```